# how to create components dynamically in qml

Tags: javascript, qt, pyqt, qml, qtquick2

[How to dynamically add components in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533565/how-to-dynamically-add-components-in-qml)
I refered this link to add a component(Rectangle component) into main.qml window upon a button click in same window. 'Ubuntu.Components' is not installed in my qt. I don't know javascript. "componentCreation.js"is refered here. What does it means?
i am beginner in qml . i need to know is there a way to load qml comonents dynamically by using qml only.

Comment: You can start from [here](https://qmlbook.github.io/) or [here](https://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch13/index.html)

Comment: Yes you can load qml component dynamically using only QML. But what are you trying to achieve? Your question should mention that, as well as your attempts at solving you issues.

Comment: thanks for commenting.!! the documents were helpful. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html        was also hepful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id:appWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    property int count: 0
    signal forward
    function fun1(argument1){
     console.log("A function fun1()in the main QML file is invoked by dynmic object")
     console.log("Returned parameter from the QML dynamic objects = ", argument1)
     }

    Item {
        id: root
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.width
        function createItem() {
            Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.5; Rectangle { x: 100; y: 100; width: 100; height: 100; color: \"blue\" }", root, "dynamicItem");
        }
    }

    Button{
        width: 200
        height: 50
        text:"Click Me"
        y:400
        x:350
        onClicked: {
            count++
            if(count==1)
            Qt.createComponent("Sprite.qml").createObject(appWindow, {"x": 100, "y": 100});
            if(count===2){
                appWindow.forward()
            }
       }
   }
   onForward:console.log("forward signal is emitted in main QML")
}
```

Sprite.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id:idRect
    signal buttonClicked()
    width: 80;
    height: 50;
    color: "red";
    x:10;
    y:100
    property string fromCallee:'This value is send signal argument'
    signal send(string pass);
    MouseArea {
                  id: leftMouseArea
                  anchors.fill: parent
                  onClicked:idRect.buttonClicked()
              }
     Component.onCompleted:{
     forward.connect(fun2);
     send.connect(fun1);
     send(fromCallee);
     }
      function fun2(){
          console.log('signal received at dynamic object')
          console.log("value of main qml property 'count'="+count)
      }
}
```